# JavaScrip file is not loaded correctly

Tags: zig

I'm trying to write a simple server that is loaded static files, so i wrote the below:

```
const std = @import("std");
const http = std.http;
const log = std.log.scoped(.server);

const server_addr = "127.0.0.1";
const server_port = 8000;

// Run the server and handle incoming requests.
fn runServer(server: *http.Server, allocator: std.mem.Allocator) !void {
    outer: while (true) {
        // Accept incoming connection.
        var response = try server.accept(.{
            .allocator = allocator,
        });
        defer response.deinit();

        // Avoid Nagle's algorithm.
        // <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm>
        try std.os.setsockopt(
            response.connection.stream.handle,
            std.os.IPPROTO.TCP,
            std.os.TCP.NODELAY,
            &std.mem.toBytes(@as(c_int, 1)),
        );

        while (response.reset() != .closing) {
            // Handle errors during request processing.
            response.wait() catch |err| switch (err) {
                error.HttpHeadersInvalid => continue :outer,
                error.EndOfStream => continue,
                else => return err,
            };

            // Process the request.
            try handleRequest(&response, allocator);
        }
        log.err("browser closed", .{});
    }
}

// Handle an individual request.
fn handleRequest(response: *http.Server.Response, allocator: std.mem.Allocator) !void {
    // Log the request details.
    log.info("{s} {s} {s}", .{ @tagName(response.request.method), @tagName(response.request.version), response.request.target });

    // Read the request body.
    const body = try response.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, 8192);
    defer allocator.free(body);

    // Set "connection" header to "keep-alive" if present in request headers.
    if (response.request.headers.contains("connection")) {
        try response.headers.append("connection", "keep-alive");
    }

    // Check if the request target starts with "/".
    if (std.mem.startsWith(u8, response.request.target, "/")) {
        const file = "index.html";
        const contents = try readFile(allocator, file);
        defer allocator.free(contents);
        std.debug.print("Now printing the file contents after clearing the memory:\n{s}\n", .{contents});


        response.transfer_encoding = .chunked;
        // Set "content-type" header to "text/plain" or text/html.
        try response.headers.append("content-type", "text/html"); // text/plain
        // Write the response body.
        try response.do();
        if (response.request.method != .HEAD) {
            try response.writeAll(contents);
            try response.finish();
        }
    } else {
        // Set the response status to 404 (not found).
        response.status = .not_found;
        try response.do();
    }
}

pub fn main() !void {
    // Create an allocator.
    const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;

    // Initialize the server.
    var server = http.Server.init(allocator, .{ .reuse_address = true });
    defer server.deinit();

    // Log the server address and port.
    log.info("Server is running at {s}:{d}", .{ server_addr, server_port });

    // Parse the server address.
    const address = std.net.Address.parseIp(server_addr, server_port) catch unreachable;
    try server.listen(address);

    // Run the server.
    runServer(&server, allocator) catch |err| {
        // Handle server errors.
        log.err("server error: {}\n", .{err});
        if (@errorReturnTrace()) |trace| {
            std.debug.dumpStackTrace(trace.*);
        }
        std.os.exit(1);
    };
}

pub fn readFile(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, filename: []const u8) ![]u8 {
    const file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile(filename, .{});
    defer file.close();

    const contents = try file.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, std.math.maxInt(usize));
    errdefer allocator.free(contents);

    return contents;
}
```

My `index.html` file is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<body>
    <h4>Hello html</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `main.js` file is:

```
console.log("Hello JavaScript");
```

The html file is loaded correctly, but the JavaScript file is not called, and I'm getting the error:

```bash
unexpected `</` at `<script src="main.js"></script>`
```

I think I need to do something regarding the mime type, but not sure if this is correct or no, and if this is the missing part, what and where is the missing code?

Comment: You don't have any code loads `main.js`. You only call `readFile` once, and there with a  `file` paramater of `index.html`. Depending on whether `request.target` starts with `/` or not, the request for `main.js` either returns the content of `index.html` or a 404 error.

Comment: @derpirscher, I thought the html file will call it, I have no idea how to manage it, do you have?

Comment: While rendering the html file, the browswer will issue a `GET /main.js` request to your backend, which you have to handle correctly. Ie in your requesthandler, check the value of `request.target` and read the correct file and set the correct mimetype

Answer (score 0):

I got the static files loaded as below:

```
const std = @import("std");
const hash = @import("./hash.zig");
const http = std.http;
const log = std.log.scoped(.server);

const server_addr = "127.0.0.1";
const server_port = 8000;

// Run the server and handle incoming requests.
fn runServer(server: *http.Server, allocator: std.mem.Allocator) !void {
    outer: while (true) {
        // Accept incoming connection.
        var response = try server.accept(.{
            .allocator = allocator,
        });
        defer response.deinit();

        // Avoid Nagle's algorithm.
        // <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm>
        try std.os.setsockopt(
            response.connection.stream.handle,
            std.os.IPPROTO.TCP,
            std.os.TCP.NODELAY,
            &std.mem.toBytes(@as(c_int, 1)),
        );

        while (response.reset() != .closing) {
            // Handle errors during request processing.
            response.wait() catch |err| switch (err) {
                error.HttpHeadersInvalid => continue :outer,
                error.EndOfStream => continue,
                else => return err,
            };

            // Process the request.
            handleRequest(&response, allocator) catch |err| {
                log.err("Error {any}", .{err});
                continue :outer;
            };
        }
        log.err("browser closed", .{});
    }
}

// Handle an individual request.
fn handleRequest(response: *http.Server.Response, allocator: std.mem.Allocator) !void {
    // Log the request details.
    log.info("{s} {s} {s}", .{ @tagName(response.request.method), @tagName(response.request.version), response.request.target });

    // Read the request body.
    const body = try response.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, 8192);
    defer allocator.free(body);

    // Set "connection" header to "keep-alive" if present in request headers.
    if (response.request.headers.contains("connection")) {
        try response.headers.append("connection", "keep-alive");
    }

    const target = response.request.target;
    const method = response.request.method;
    log.debug("target: {any}/{s}", .{ method, target });

    if (std.mem.startsWith(u8, target, "/favicon.ico")) {
        return error.FaviconNotFound;
    }

    response.transfer_encoding = .chunked;

    if (std.mem.containsAtLeast(u8, target, 1, ".")) {
        // Set "content-type" header to "text/html".
        const file = std.mem.trimLeft(u8, target, &[_]u8{'/'});

        // Check the MIME type based on the file extension
        // const extension = std.fs.path.extension(file);

        // var mimeTypes = std.StringHashMap([]const u8).init(allocator);
        // try hash.init(&mimeTypes);
        // defer mimeTypes.deinit();
        // if (mimeTypes.get(extension)) |mimeType| {
        //     try response.headers.append("content-type", mimeType);
        //     std.debug.print("The MIME type for {s} is {s}\n", .{ extension, mimeType });
        // } else {
        //     log.err("Unknown extension: {s}", .{extension});
        //     return error.UnKnownExtension;
        // }

        // Or use instead if if do not want to use HashMap
        // if (std.mem.eql(u8, extension, ".html")) {
        try response.headers.append("content-type", "text/html");
        // } else if (std.mem.eql(u8, extension, ".js")) {
        //     try response.headers.append("content-type", "application/javascript");
        // } else if (std.mem.eql(u8, extension, ".css")) {
        //     try response.headers.append("content-type", "text/css");
        // } else {
        //     log.err("Unknown extension: {s}", .{extension});
        //     try response.headers.append("content-type", "text/plain");
        // }

        const contents = readFile(allocator, file) catch |err| {
            log.err("Error reading file {s} => {any}", .{ file, err });
            return error.FileNotFound;
        };
        log.info("file read as: \n{s}", .{contents});
        // Write the response body.
        try response.do();
        if (response.request.method != .HEAD) {
            try response.writeAll(contents);
            try response.finish();
            allocator.free(contents);
        }
    } else {
        // Set "content-type" header to "text/plain".
        try response.headers.append("content-type", "text/plain");

        // Write the response body.
        try response.do();
        if (response.request.method != .HEAD) {
            try response.writeAll("Zig ");
            try response.writeAll("Bits!\n");
            try response.writeAll(target);
            try response.finish();
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() !void {
    // Create an allocator.
    const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;

    // Initialize the server.
    var server = http.Server.init(allocator, .{ .reuse_address = true });
    defer server.deinit();

    // Log the server address and port.
    log.info("Server is running at {s}:{d}", .{ server_addr, server_port });

    // Parse the server address.
    const address = std.net.Address.parseIp(server_addr, server_port) catch unreachable;
    try server.listen(address);

    // Run the server.
    runServer(&server, allocator) catch |err| {
        // Handle server errors.
        log.err("server error: {}\n", .{err});
        if (@errorReturnTrace()) |trace| {
            std.debug.dumpStackTrace(trace.*);
        }
        std.os.exit(1);
    };
}

pub fn readFile(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, filename: []const u8) ![]u8 {
    const file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile(filename, .{});
    defer file.close();

    const contents = try file.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, std.math.maxInt(usize));
    errdefer allocator.free(contents);

    return contents;
}
```

Though I found it is not required to add the MIME type, but below is the file I used to define the main MIMEs:

```
// hash.zig
const std = @import("std");

pub fn init(mimeTypes: *std.StringHashMap([]const u8)) !void {
    try mimeTypes.put(".html", "text/html");
    try mimeTypes.put(".js", "application/javascript");
    try mimeTypes.put(".css", "text/css");
}
```